# Isomorphism between two spaces, one of them is a Banach Space.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a Banach space. And $X$ be normed vector space.

If we have an isomorphism between $E$ and $X$. can we prove then that $X$ is also a Banach space ?

(In other words, does isomorphism conserves the Banach structure ? )

Comment: When you say "isomorphism" do you mean isomorphism of vector spaces or isomorphism of topological vector spaces?

Comment: topological vector space

Comment: Check if your function is uniformly continuous in both directions (this is the case for bounded linear maps), then it preserves cauchy sequences and convergence sequences in both direction.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639544/can-a-continuous-map-between-a-banach-space-and-a-non-banach-space-be-bijective

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Not a duplicate, since an isomorphism of topological vector spaces is not only a continuous map, but actually a homemorphism.  So the counterexamples given in that answer don't apply, and the answer to this one is yes instead of no.

Comment: @NateEldredge By mistake I quoted  a wrong post. I am aware of the  fact that the answer is yes and I have upvoted the comment by Math_QED. I am pretty sure this question has been asked on MSE since it is quite elementary. Thanks for your comment.